# Xubuntu 18.04 update error

Tags: grub2, updates, xubuntu, 18.04

Strange update error appeared while upgrading all other updates setting up fine just this two:
`grub-efi-amd64-signed/bionic-updates 1.93.2+2.02-2ubuntu8.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.93.1+2.02-2ubuntu8.1]
unattended-upgrades/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.1 all [upgradable from: 1.1ubuntu1]`

Give me this error:

```
File descriptor 4 (/dev/sda1) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 9320: grub-install
File descriptor 4 (/dev/sda1) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 9320: grub-install
grub-install: error: attempt to install to encrypted disk without cryptodisk enabled. Set `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y' in file `/etc/default/grub'.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10) ...
Setting up unattended-upgrades (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.1) ...
Replacing config file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades with new version
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this error appeared because grub was tried to make changes to unencrypted file.

To fix this issue you have to add following line: `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y`
in to a file `/etc/default/grub`

After this everything updates as it should.

Don't know why this error appear from the start.

[EDITED]

If you fix this error as I did, it will breake your GRUB loader, ad you gonna heave to restore it.